# laravel 9 form validation error has space between field name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-form, laravel-formrequest

There are space comes after every character of field name while displaying errors in blade template in laravel 9 as mentioned in uploaded image

[image: LARAVEL9 FORM IMAGE]
my code is mentioned as below

### CODE IN HTML IS :

```
<form action="{{route('saveAsset')}}" method="post">
                {{@csrf_field()}}
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="assetTitle" class="mt-2 mb-2">{{$assetCategory->category}} TITLE :</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="assetTitle" id="assetTitle" placeholder="Enter Asset Title">
                </div>
                <div class="inputError">@error('assetTitle') Error: {{ $message }} @enderror </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="assetCateId" id="assetCateId" value="{{$assetCategory->id}}">
                
                @if(count($attributes) > 0)
                    @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
                        <label for="assetType-{{$attribute->attr_id}}" class="mt-4 mb-2">{{$attribute->attr_title}} : </label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-select" name="{{$attribute->attr_title}}" id="attribute-{{$attribute->attr_id}}" aria-label="Default select example">
                                <option value="">Select {{$attribute->attr_title}}</option>
                                @foreach($attrValues as $attrValue)
                                    @if ($attrValue->attr_id == $attribute->attr_id && strlen($attrValue->value) > 0 )
                                    <option value="{{$attribute->attr_id}}-{{$attrValue->value_id}}" > {{$attrValue->value}}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputError"> @error("{$attribute->attr_title}") Error: {{ $message }} @enderror </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 px-4">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

### CODE IN CONTROLLER IS :

```
$fields = $req->input();
       

        $ValidationRules=[];
        foreach($fields as $fieldName=>$fieldvalue){
            
            if($fieldName == "assetTitle"){
                $ValidationRules[$fieldName] = 'required|unique:assets,title';
            }else{
                $ValidationRules[$fieldName] = 'required';
            }
        }
        $req->validate($ValidationRules);
```

Comment: Maybe a CSS issue? :/

Comment: This smells like an issue with custom validation messages. Can you check that out?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you still need help but I just had the same issue and I think it's because you might have the input names with text uppercase, laravel automaticly adds a space for each uppercase character in the name attribute when showing the errors.

For example:
name="thisModel"

Will display as:
... this Model ...

If you have:
name="MODEL"

Will display as:
... M O D E L ...

Hope this helps someone in the future x)

Comment: It's possible to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and this is how I fixed it. I added a custom attribute array to the validator. Seems a bit much, but it works...

```
// Create an array when the key and value match, one row for each attribute
$attributes = [];
foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
   $attributes[$key] = $key;
}
```

And then I send these attributes to the validator:

```
/** @var Illuminate\Validation\Factory $factory */
$factory = app('validator');
$validator = $factory->make($inputData, $rules, [], $attributes);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // Ahhhh, but the error looks right!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have made some changes in `resources/lang/en/validation.php` file.
in this or any language you have set , there is a attribute named `attributes`
that you can change the the attribute name displaying in error message.
because the error message of `asset` field is ok I do not think it's a general error . check this file and `attributes` or `messages` key in it.